# Drupal 7 - theme default node view

Tags: nodes, theming

I would like to know the recommended way to re-theme the default node view for a certain content type.

E.g. http://dev.mysite/en/node/6547, now shows a 'list' of content fields. We would like to change this to a more clean layout.

Would using a node.tpl.php in the theme folder and then create a node--[TYPE].tpl.php for the specific node type solve this problem in the correct way?

Regards,
Wouter

Answer (score 1):

Using .tpl.php files would indeed give you more control over the HTML Drupal will create in the end.
Also using a module like Display Suite (DS - [drupal.org/project/ds](http://drupal.org/project/ds)) will give you more control over the fields in a certain display so that some settings about that field on that display are stored in database instead of in code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You are on the right track...

For more information on templates please see [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)

You can override specific nodes of a type using below tpl file name

```
node--type.tpl.php
```

To print fields in node tpl you can use below code

```
<?php print render($content['your_field_name']); ?>
```